# Change password programmatically

Tags: macos, password, keychain

I am looking for a simple method to change password with a script on macOS 10.12.6 (or newer).

I tried something like

```
sudo yes "mynewpassword" | sudo passwd myuser
```

But this is not working, apparently `passwd` is not reading from stdin.

I wonder if there is a official method to do so, like a command line tool.